# issue with case statement

Tags: sql, case, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Input data:

| NUMBER | FLAG_1 | FLAG_2 | FLAG_3 | FLAG_4 | FLAG_5 | FLAG_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | X | X | X | X | X | X |

Case stmt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
NUMBER,
CASE 
    WHEN FLAG_1='X' AND FLAG_2='X' AND FLAG_3='X' THEN 'PRE'
    WHEN FLAG_4='X' AND FLAG_5='X' AND FLAG_6='X' THEN 'POST'
ELSE 'NA' END
AS FLAG 

FROM TABLE
```

output of my query:

| NUMBER | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | PRE |

expected:

| NUMBER | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | PRE |
| 123456 | POST |

how the quyery can be tweaked?

Comment: Can you show us some more sample table data and the expected result - covering the three different cases. Use properly formatted text, not images or links to images.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `case` *expression* returns the value for the first TRUE `when`, your sample row's 'POST' will never be found.

Simple trick that will work fine for you is a `UNION`, where you have the `case` twice, with switched condition orders.

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER,
    CASE 
        WHEN FLAG_1='X' AND FLAG_2='X' AND FLAG_3='X' THEN 'PRE'
        WHEN FLAG_4='X' AND FLAG_5='X' AND FLAG_6='X' THEN 'POST'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS FLAG 
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT 
    NUMBER,
    CASE 
        WHEN FLAG_4='X' AND FLAG_5='X' AND FLAG_6='X' THEN 'POST'
        WHEN FLAG_1='X' AND FLAG_2='X' AND FLAG_3='X' THEN 'PRE'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS FLAG 
FROM TABLE
```